# How to store integer indexed data in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm coming from working in PHP for many years and having trouble wrapping my head around creating some more complicated data structures in JS for objects that are integer IDed. I need to build an object the stores these simpler objects hierarchically keyed on their integer ids. So if I have the following objectes each of which has a unique integer id:

section, element, item, entry

in php I would do something like

```
$arr[$section_id][$element_id][$item_id][$entry_id] = $entry;
```

In javascript this does not work. I know I could technically wrap those IDs in quotes to force it but that seems like a bad idea. Similarly I could create an object and use the quoted integer approach but again that seems hacky.

Right now I am storing the data in regular integer indexed arrays and then using caolan's async detect to look up a particular member by ID. This works but seems extremely messy compared to the php equivalent. I'm hoping there's a cleaner way to do this in JS.

TIA!

Comment: it's not very difficult to check at each nesting level if the next property exists and create it as needed...question hard to answer without understanding use case better

Comment: a json object {} can act as an associative key/pair associations

Comment: Can you at least provide an example JSON data?

Comment: @YounElan  no such thing as a `JSON object`..JSON is a string

Answer (score 0):

since javascript cannot save an array with string index, i use these :

```
var namespace = function(name, separator, container){
  var ns = name.split(separator || '.')
    , o = container || window
    , i = 0;
  while (i++ < ns.length) o = o[ns[i - 1]] = o[ns[i - 1]] || {};
  return o;
}

namespace(arr + '.' + section_id + '.' + element_id + '.' + item_id + '.' + entry_id) = entry;
// ex : namespace('arr.1.3.2.6') will product arr.1.3.2.6 object
```

Comment: not entirely true.  Objects are just associative arrays.  In fact, this will run just fine.   http://jsfiddle.net/tomprogramming/5xYRw/

Answer (score 0):

This is a little ugly, but it will get you pretty close to what you want.

You can add a method to the JavaScript Array class like so:

```
Array.prototype.g = function(index) { 
    if (this[index] == undefined) { 
         this[index] = [];
    } 
    return this[index]; 
 }
```

Then, to set something you would do this:

```
var test = [];
test.g(5).g(7)[5] = 1;
```

Unfortunately, for the last entry you'd have to remember to use the regular notation to set the value.

You would retrieve it like you expect:

```
test[5][7][5]; //1
```

Obviously I just pulled g out of thin air, you could come up with your own function name.

Disclaimer:  People tend to frown on extending the built in types using the prototype chain, but as far as I know most major frameworks no longer do this so unless you or some third party JS is using the same name to extend Array somewhere else you should be fine.